# How do I set up a criteria using the second column of a combo box in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox, criteria

I have a combo box that selects an angle.
I want to use this angle as a limit.

The combo box uses this table:

[image: Table]

The combo box displays column(1) (BaseCoordinates)

I need to create a criteria in a query like this:

[image: Criteria]

But of course it picks the ID as it is the first column.
I have fixed this earlier by not having an ID on the table, but i don't like that because it may order the numbers in a way I don't want it to, if i have only the column with the values.

I have tried doing `forms!f_main!WindSectorCombo.Column(1)` but it can not recognize the variable.

In VBA, it can easily find the variable - The problem is in the query.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try changing the Bound column from 1 to 2?

Comment: Yes, it doesnt even recognize the command, despites using 0, 1 or 2.

Comment: No. What I meant was, in the design view of the ComboBox, change the property of the Bound Column to 2 from 1. So you do not have to use the Column method in Query. It could be simply `Forms!FormName!ComboBoxName`

Comment: Oh yes, i see now what you mean. I have not tried to change the bound column, but it makes sense that it would fix the issue. I will try it asap. I dont have any tables now because i had to make a quickfix by having only 1 column to move on. But i will let you know if it worked. And thank you both very much!

Answer (score 1):

As PaulFrancis suggested, you need to make sure that the bound column is your BaseCoordinates column.

Go to the property sheet of WindSectorCombo, and under the data tab, put 2 if in the design view of your data origin query, the BaseCoordinates column is in the 2nd position

In the format tab on the property sheet of WindSectorCombo, make sure that the number of columns is 2 and the width of the second column is more than zero (to be able to see the value in your combo box)

now select a value from WindSectorCombo on your form and run your query again and it will work. Your query SQL should look something like this:

```
SELECT myTable.ID, myTable.BaseCoordinates
FROM myTable
WHERE ((myTable.BaseCoordinates)>(90-([Forms]![f_Main]![WindSectorCombo])));
```

Comment: I will try asap, thank you! (See reply to paul and you above)